# how to get only unique values from dropdown menu on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering how to get only unique values from dropdown menu. code.correct_answers has some duplicate options like count, n, stepper and stepper.

```
 <%= form.select :variable, options_from_collection_for_select(code.correct_answers, :variable, :variable, "#{ student_answer.variable if student_answer.present? }"), prompt: 'Choose variable' %>
```

I tried to put .uniq or .distinct behind () like below

```
<%= form.select :variable, options_from_collection_for_select(code.correct_answers, :variable, :variable, "#{ student_answer.variable if student_answer.present? }").uniq, prompt: 'Choose variable' %>
```

However, it dose not work... The dropdown menu still has duplicate options. How can I get only unique values from dropdown menu?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the collection as first parameter to the `options_from_collection_for_select` method ([documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select)). If you want to make sure that there is no duplicate options, you have to make sure the collection you pass in has no duplicates.

This means you have to apply the `uniq` to `code.correct_answers`.

```
<%= form.select :variable, options_from_collection_for_select(code.correct_answers.uniq, :variable, :variable, "#{ student_answer.variable if student_answer.present? }"), prompt: 'Choose variable' %>
```

The reason why your approach doesn't work is that `options_from_collection_for_select` returns distinct tags. Hence, an applied `uniq` (with the default comparison) to these tags returns the same collection.

Comment: yeah I just tried this way, but it still shows duplicate options...

Comment: Hi - Could you please provide more context in your question? It'd be good to know how the return result of `core.correct_answers` looks.

Comment: it still shows duplicate like <select name="student_answer[variable]" id="student_answer_variable"><option value="">Choose variable</option>
<option selected="selected" value="count">count</option>
<option value="n">n</option>
<option value="1233123">1233123</option>
<option value="1233123">1233123</option></select> 1233123 is duplicate

Comment: Hi - I understand this is the output but we'll need to know the _input_, i.e. the contents of `code.correct_answers`. Could you add `<%= debug code.correct_answers %>` to your template and copy the output into your question? Thank you.